# Why cannot head element be styled?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head style="border:2px solid black;">
  <p>dgdgsdg</p>
</head>



</html>
```

Why cannot head element in this code be styled ? Is it because head element can only have metadata and hence cannot be styled ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can. It is just `display: none` by default because it doesn't contain any data that *should* be part of the display. (Elements that have `display: none` aren't rendered, so any border on them would not be shown.) It only contains things like references to stylesheets and the `<title>` (which is rendered outside of the viewport).

```css
head {
    display: block;
    border:2px solid black;
    height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>dgdgsdg</title>
</head>
</html>
```

In your example you have tried to put a `<p>` element inside the `<head>`. **This is invalid HTML**.

The start tag for the `<p>` **implicitly ends the head element** and starts the body element. Then your `</head>` tag gets discarded because it doesn't match any open element.

Use a [markup validator](https://validator.nu/) to find this kind of error.

You might be confusing the [head element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) with the [header element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header).

Comment: That last part was most helpful. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, head is kind of container for metadata, therefore its contents are not displayed. As far as i know, only following elements can go inside `<head>` tag:

```
<title> 
<style>
<base>
<link>
<meta>
<script>
<noscript>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `<head>` is a container for metadata, don't get confused by `<header>`, which is inside the `<body>`, and it normally contains the Logo, Navigation Menu, etc.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp